# Which verbs tense I should learn after simple present?

Tags: verb, learning

I'm studying German for a while, I know I still have a lot to learn. But I'm considering which verbs tense I should learn after Simple Present, like a study guide for verbs tense. 
Could someone give me a help?!

Comment: I should say take a short simple story and learn the first tense that occurs in the story and that you don't master. All tenses are important. A child could ask just as well: Which of the ten digits shall I learn next?

Comment: @rogermue For one you compare apples and oranges, for another not all tenses are equally important. Präsens is certainly much more frequent in use than, let's say, Futur II. I see good reason to ask in which order you should learn the tenses.

Comment: Future 1 is "er wird + infinitive" and Future 2 is "er wird + infinitive perfect". What is so difficult about such structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's not really a rule in which order you should learn tenses, but in general–disregarding the actual language–I would learn both a future and a past tense. That basically allows you to convey if something happened in the past, happens right now or is going to happen.

Luckily, in German you can express future with *Präsens*. Thus, you can focus on the past tense.

As Emanuel correctly mentioned, in spoken language Germans mainly use *Perfekt*. I am of the opinion, however, that you shouldn't ignore *Präteritum* because this is used in written text very much. Since there's technically not really a difference between those tenses (both refer to a finished action in the past), it's not a real overhead.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple:

Learn the spoken version of the past tense. And do NOT learn the preterit.

Comment: Downvoters... please explain yourself. Or would you seriously suggest that she not learn the spoken past? I mean... come on!

Comment: Preterit is very important, think of "Ich war", "Du musstest", "Sie hatte", used very often in the spoken language.

Comment: @BarthZalewski... yeah, maybe my answer wasn't clear enough. I meant that she should learn the spoken past for each verb. That can be the perfect or the preterit but for the large majority it'll be the perfect